# Which is the fastest way to read a few lines out of a large hdfs dir using spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My goal is to read a few lines out of a large hdfs dir, I'm using spark2.2.
This dir is generated by previous spark job and each task generated a single little file in the dir, so the whole dir is like 1GB size and have thousands of little files.
When I use collect() or head() or limit(), spark will load all the files, and creates thousands of tasks(monitoring in sparkUI), which costs a lot of time, even I just want to show the first few lines of the files in this dir.
So which is the fastest way to read this dir? I hope the best solution is only load only a few lines of data so it would save time.
Following is my code:
`sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferschema","true").load(file).limit(20).toJSON.toString()`

`sparkSession.sql(s"select * from $file").head(100).toString`
`sparkSession.sql(s"select * from $file").limit(100).toString`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan `take` returns an Array but I need column info, so I use sqlContext to map data into a table, can u help with that ?

Comment: if I use dataframe, spark will load data any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you directly want to use spark then it will anyways load the files and then it does taking records. So first even before spark logic you have to get one file name from the directory using ur technology like java or scala or python and pass that file name to text File method that won't load all files.

Comment: Yup but instead making spark to do that use ur own logic for that if you need it in java I can give you that

Comment: Yup get one file name by using some manipulation in logic and then pass that name to the spark text file method

Comment: I tried to get first file name but the name is random,different task generates different random names .... I'm using scala right now, can you show me a case ?

Comment: If you don't want any specific file then random is good and
The way I do in java is get the list of files in the directory and get the first file name from the list and pass it to spark to read